# Change Unity Dash to list view

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

Can I somehow change the Unity Dash so that the search results appear in a list?

I don't like that i have to use more than <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> in order to select an item and I find it hard to overview the results fast if they are spread over the entire screen.

Sorry for my pickiness, but the Dash is pretty much the only GUI element of the entire OS that I repeatedly operate, so it is quite important to me that it works well.